# MongoDB Aggregation - Lookup pipeline not returning any documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having  hard time getting `$lookup` with a `pipeline` to work in MongoDB Compass.

I have the following collections:

**Toys**

[image: First Image - Toys]

Data

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d233c3bb173a546386c59bb"
    },
    "type": "multiple",
    "tags": [
      ""
    ],
    "searchFields": [
      "Jungle Stampers - Two",
      ""
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59bd"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59be"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59bf"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59c0"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59c1"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59c2"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59c3"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5d233c3cb173a546386c59c4"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Jungle Stampers - Two",
    "description": "",
    "status": "active",
    "category": {
      "$oid": "5cfe727cac920000086b880e"
    },
    "subCategory": "Stamp Sets",
    "make": "",
    "defaultCharge": null,
    "defaultOverdue": null,
    "sizeCategory": {
      "$oid": "5d0cfde57561e107c88fbde3"
    },
    "ageFrom": {
      "$numberInt": "24"
    },
    "ageTo": {
      "$numberInt": "120"
    },
    "images": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5d233c3bb173a546386c59bc"
        },
        "id": {
          "$oid": "5d233c39b173a546386c59ba"
        },
        "url": "/toyimages/5d233c39b173a546386c59ba.jpg",
        "thumbUrl": "/toyimages/thumbs/tn_5d233c39b173a546386c59ba.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "__v": {
      "$numberInt": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

**Loans**

[image: Second Image - Loans]

Data

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5e1f1661b712215978c746d9"
    },
    "tags": [],
    "member": {
      "$oid": "5e17495e4f81ab3f900dbb63"
    },
    "source": "admin portal - potter1@gmail.com",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": {
          "$oid": "5e1f160eb712215978c746d5"
        },
        "status": "new",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5e1f1661b712215978c746db"
        },
        "toy": {
          "$oid": "5d233c3bb173a546386c59bb"
        },
        "cost": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "$oid": "5e1f160eb712215978c746d5"
        },
        "status": "new",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5e1f1661b712215978c746da"
        },
        "toy": {
          "$oid": "5d233b1ab173a546386c59b5"
        },
        "cost": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "dateEntered": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1579095632870"
      }
    },
    "dateDue": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1579651200000"
      }
    },
    "__v": {
      "$numberInt": "0"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to return a list of toys and their associated loans that have a status of 'new' or 'out'.

I can use the following `$lookup` aggregate to fetch all loans:

```json
{
  from: 'loans',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'items.toy',
  as: 'loansSimple'
}
```

However I am trying to use a pipeline to load loans that have the two statuses I am interested in, but it always only returns zero documents:

```json
{
  from: 'loans',
  let: {
    'toyid': '$_id'
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {$eq: ['$items.toy', '$$toyid']},
            {$eq: ['$items.status', 'new']} // changed from $in to $eq for simplicity
          ]
        }
      }
    }  
  ],
  as: 'loans'
}
```

This always seems to return 0 documents, however I arrange it:

[image: Image Three - Results]

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

I'm using MongoDB Atlas, v4.2.2, MongoDB Compass v 1.20.4

Comment: Can you post sample data as ´text´ please?

Comment: @Valijon I'll add it, struggling to get it formatted though so excuse the format

Comment: You may use https://mongoplayground.net/ to format

Comment: @Valijon Added formatted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to search `$$toyid` inside inner array, but Operator Expression `$eq` cannot resolve it.

**Best solution:** `$let` (returns filtered `loans` by criteria) + `$filter` (applies filter for inner array) operator helps us to get desired result.

```
db.toys.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "loans",
      let: {
        "toyid": "$_id",
        "toystatus": "new"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $size: {
                    $let: {
                      vars: {
                        item: {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$items",
                            as: "tmp",
                            cond: {
                              $and: [
                                {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$tmp.toy",
                                    "$$toyid"
                                  ]
                                },
                                {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$tmp.status",
                                    "$$toystatus"
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      in: "$$item"
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "loans"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5gFaZtB3thg)

**Alternative solution 1.** Use `$unwind` to flatten `items` attribute. (We create extra field named `tmp` which stores `items` value, flatten it with `$unwind` operator, match as you were doing and then exclude from result)

```
db.toys.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "loans",
      let: {
        "toyid": "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            tmp: "$items"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$tmp"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$tmp.toy",
                    "$$toyid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$tmp.status",
                    "new"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            tmp: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "loans"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SYBFb3Jk25X)

**Alternative solution 2**. We use `$reduce` to create toy's array and with `$in` operator we check if `toyid` exists inside this array.

```
db.toys.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "loans",
      let: {
        "toyid": "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            toys: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$items",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    [
                      "$$this.toy"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$toyid",
                "$toys"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            toys: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "loans"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: "Best solution" was the cleanest and seems best performing, using this one, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't know `$let` operator can return arrays / object / object fields and I was near to open a new task in MongoDB JIRA to implement something like this... Excellent question!

Answer (score 1):

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) receives [aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions), At that point `$$items.toy` is parsed for each element in an array as you would expect (however if it would it will still give you "bad" results as you'll get loans that have the required toy id  and any other item with status `new` in their items array).

So you have two options to work around this:

1. If you don't care about the other items in the lookup'd document you can add an `$unwind` stage at the start of the lookup pipeline like so:

```
{
    from: 'loans',
    let: {
        'toyid': '$_id'
    },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $unwind: "$items"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        {$eq: ['$items.toy', '$$toyid']},
                        {$eq: ['$items.status', 'new']} // changed from $in to $eq for simplicity
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    as: 'loans'
}
```

2. If you do care about them just iterate the array in one of the possible ways to get a 'correct' match, here is an example using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
    {
        from: 'loads',
        let: {
            'toyid': '$_id'
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $addFields: {
                    temp: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$items",
                            as: "item",
                            cond: {
                                $and: [
                                    {$eq: ["$$item.toy", "$$toyid"]},
                                    {$eq: ["$$item.status", "new"]}
                                ]
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

            }, {$match: {"temp.0": {exists: true}}}
        ],
        as: 'loans'
    }
```